# passing Doctrine\DBAL\Statement as argument to service

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine, arguments

I Have a symfony service i want to pass Doctrine\DBAL\Statement as argument
but it's not working i have this in my config

```
topic_repo:
        class: ApiBundle\Repository\TopicRepository
        arguments:
              - '@database_connection'
              - '@Doctrine.debal.statement'
```

i'm getting The service "topic_repo" has a dependency on a non-existent service

Comment: Because there is no Doctrine.debal.statement service tag and its DBAL not DEBAL

and why you need a database connection in a repository you can make a simple use in the repository instead

Comment: i know there is no bdal service that's why i'm asking if there is a way to pass the statement natively in symfony or i would have to create it's own service, like i said this is a service not a repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by defining statement as service then pass it to my topicRepo service

```
doctrine_statement:
     class: Doctrine\DBAL\Statement
     arguments:
           - 'sql'
           - '@database_connection'
```

Answer (score 0):

A repository should not be depending on a service (you want to keep things separated).
What you could do is creating a BaseRepository or something similar which contains any standard respository functionality you might need and from which your Repository is extending then.

Comment: it's not a repository linked to an entity, it's a service.
i don't want to use repository.

Comment: so ApiBundle\Repository\TopicRepository isn't a repository?

Comment: no, it's a service. can be confusing, but i just needed not to use orm, forget the name, assume we have a service want to pass statement as argument, how it will be?